# Override action in JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my requirement, a user can select multiple check-boxes. However after checking each check-box I need to call the URL and pass selected checkbox value with time-delay of 3 seconds. This delay is required, so that user can select/de-select another checkbox, old action should be canceled and new selected value(s) should be passed.

I know to call a function with delay, but don't know how to stop the last action with the new one.

```
setTimeout(function(){ call_me(action) },3000);
function call_me(action)
{
    var url = action
    $(location).attr('href',url);
}
```

Comment: You can use `clearTimeOut` to stop the current animation by passing an id on the `setTimeOut` which you will use as a parameter to the `clearTimeOut` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `clearTimeout()`, but first you need to assign the return of the setTimeout to a variable.

```
// declared outside of your code that sets the timeout.
var t;


// your code to be run when you want to set the timeout
clearTimeout(t);  // if there is no timeout already assigned to t, this line does nothing.
t = setTimeout(function(){ call_me(action) },3000);
function call_me(action)
{
    var url = action
    $(location).attr('href',url);
}
```

Comment: Seems someone thought my answer was not correct.  Could one of our senior members point out why, or better yet post the better answer?... please? :S